# How to print the value in front of label?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I have written a program which is using TensorFlow Lite to classify images. Now the result gets stored in a List like 
`[{confidence: 0.9617149829864502, index: 1, label: 1 Funny}]`

this is the first element of the array. Now I want to show the value next to label in my app as a Text Widget. Eg: Funny.
How can I do so

Comment: Are you asking to do something like: `Text(yourFlowData[idx]["label"])`?

Comment: I tried that but it is giving error

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: It worked. Actually I was trying ("label"). Thanx.

Comment: but how do I remove 1 from the beginning

Comment: You can use `List.remove(Object)` or `List.removeAt(int)` and others. See [List](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/List-class.html) docs.

Comment: You're welcome. Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

`Text(yourFlowData[idx]["label"])`

Thanks to @hola for helping me out.